# Why local images saved in Room database are not displayed after i restart an app?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-jetpack-compose

I'm saving uri's as a string in Room database, then the app is retrieving data and displaying all the images in the LazyVerticalGrid. When i add images, everything works fine, all the images are displayed correctly. The problem is when i restart an app. All the images disappears and when i add exactly the same image (with the same uri) - it appear in the first position, but also in all the positions before i restarted an app. When i check the logs, all uri's are also retrieved correctly from database as format:

content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A9371

Here is the code for Image showing (using coil):

```
@Composable
fun ProfilePhotoView(photo: String, navController: NavHostController) {
    Image(
        painter = rememberImagePainter(photo),
        contentDescription = null,
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
        modifier = Modifier
            .aspectRatio(1f)
            .padding(3.dp)
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
            .clickable {},
        alignment = Alignment.Center
    )
    Log.i(TAG,"photo string = ${photo}")
}
```

And here is how i retrieve an uri before adding to database:

```
val selectImagelauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract =
        ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()
    ) { uri: Uri? ->
        imageUriState = uri
    }
selectImagelauncher.launch("image/*")
```

Do you have any idea why i can't display images with "old" uri before adding the same image into database?

Comment: %3A is an encoded character, are you sure you're decoding it correctly?

Comment: i believe i do, because before i restart an app, every images are displayed correctly

Comment: Also when i retrieve data from gallery, not from document, the format is:
content://media/external/images/media/9323 and nothing changes

Comment: Before storing it it's probably not encoded. Did you debug to check the original URI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm saving uri's as a string in Room database

With your existing code, that will not work. Normally, [you only have access rights to the content from within the activity that receives the `Uri`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/10/uri-access-lifetime-shorter-than-you-might-think.html). Once your process terminates, all access rights are lost.

If you change `ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()` to `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument()`, and you call `takePersistableUriPermission()` on a `ContentResolver` for the `Uri` that you get, then you have long-term access to the content.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own ActivityResultContract,
for your case

contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
this is after pickup Uri

```
class GetPicturesContract : ActivityResultContract<String, Uri?>() {
override fun createIntent(context: Context, input: String?): Intent {
    return Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
        .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        .setType(input)
}

override fun getSynchronousResult(
    context: Context,
    input: String
): SynchronousResult<Uri?>? {
    return null
}

override fun parseResult(resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?): Uri? {
    return if (intent == null || resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) null else intent.data
}
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).